# Feeding audio from iPad into digital piano speakers

Tags: digital-piano, homerecording, garage-band

I have a Yamaha P-115 digital piano which has a USB port. I just purchased an iPad and want to use GarageBand and other apps to digitally record music.

I understand that I can connect my iPad to my Yamaha P-115 through that USB port but if I understand it correctly, when I do that the audio will come from the iPad.

Clearly the Yamaha P-115 has better speakers than the iPad so I was wondering if there is a way to feed the audio coming from the iPad back into the piano. If so, how do I do it and do I need any connectors, etc.?

Comment: Have you read the iPhone/iPad Connection Manual https://download.yamaha.com/migrated_files/57948.pdf referenced in the P-115 manual https://jp.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/333278/p115_en_om_b0.pdf?

Comment: Thanks for the links but I didn’t find any information about feeding the audio output from the iPad back into the piano. What is the typical setup when connecting a digital piano to iPhone/iPad for audio output?